# Getting Error Before Installing PHP Script ( Mysql Database Connection Error )

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error while installing a script.

Error Message :

```
 Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/*******/public_html/*********.com/includes/tables.php on line 0

Line Contains Only This (This Is Content Of The Entire Tables.php)

<?php //0035e
if(!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader')){$__oc=strtolower(substr(php_uname(),0,3));$__ln='/ioncube/ioncube_loader_'.$__oc.'_'.substr(phpversion(),0,3).(($__oc=='win')?'.dll':'.so');$__oid=$__id=realpath(ini_get('extension_dir'));$__here=dirname(__FILE__);if(strlen($__id)>1&&$__id[1]==':'){$__id=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__id,2));$__here=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__here,2));}$__rd=str_repeat('/..',substr_count($__id,'/')).$__here.'/';$__i=strlen($__rd);while($__i--){if($__rd[$__i]=='/'){$__lp=substr($__rd,0,$__i).$__ln;if(file_exists($__oid.$__lp)){$__ln=$__lp;break;}}}@dl($__ln);}else{die('The file '.__FILE__." is corrupted.\n");}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}echo('Site error: the file <b>'.__FILE__.'</b> requires the ionCube PHP Loader '.basename($__ln).' to be installed by the site administrator.');exit(199);
?>
```

Comment: Check, that you use correct mysql credentials.

Comment: Thanks , BTW , Problem Solved.

I Forgot To Link The Database User To The Database .. 

xD